# Is it possible to work with text using hover or the select tool?

Tags: python, bokeh

Is it possible to use the hover/select tool with bokeh text glyphs?

Using the same basic setup, I can get great tool tips with the hover tool on circle glyphs, but not text glyphs

```py
import numpy
import pandas
from bokeh import charts, plotting, models
plotting.output_notebook()

blue = 'STEELBLUE'
green = 'FORESTGREEN'

datalist = [
    {'month': 'Oct', 'rain': 131., 'snow':  0.0, 'wy_month': 1},
    {'month': 'Nov', 'rain': 12.4, 'snow':  0.0, 'wy_month': 2},
    {'month': 'Dec', 'rain': 43.0, 'snow': 13.5, 'wy_month': 3},
    {'month': 'Jan', 'rain': 63.0, 'snow':  9.2, 'wy_month': 4},
    {'month': 'Feb', 'rain': 72.6, 'snow': 35.3, 'wy_month': 5},
    {'month': 'Mar', 'rain': 13.5, 'snow':  4.2, 'wy_month': 6},
    {'month': 'Apr', 'rain': 107., 'snow':  1.5, 'wy_month': 7},
    {'month': 'May', 'rain': 77.0, 'snow':  0.0, 'wy_month': 8},
    {'month': 'Jun', 'rain': 107., 'snow':  0.0, 'wy_month': 9},
    {'month': 'Jul', 'rain': 216., 'snow':  0.0, 'wy_month': 10},
    {'month': 'Aug', 'rain': 76.8, 'snow':  0.0, 'wy_month': 11},
    {'month': 'Sep', 'rain': 76.4, 'snow':  0.0, 'wy_month': 12}
]

data = pandas.DataFrame(datalist).assign(total=lambda df: df['rain'] + df['snow'])
source = plotting.ColumnDataSource(data)

tooltips = [
    ("month", "@month"),
    ("rain", "@rain"),
    ("snow", "@snow"),
]
```

Working version for circle

```py
hover_circle = models.HoverTool(tooltips=tooltips)
TOOLS_circle = [hover_circle, models.ResetTool(), models.BoxSelectTool()]

fig = plotting.figure(width=600, height=300, y_range=(0, 250),
                      x_range=data['month'].tolist(),
                      tools=TOOLS_circle)
fig.circle(x='wy_month', y='rain', color=blue, source=source, selection_color = "orange", nonselection_alpha=0.2)
fig.circle(x='wy_month', y='snow', color=green, source=source, selection_color = "orange", nonselection_alpha=0.2)
plotting.show(fig)
```

Circles can be selected and change color.

Non working version for text

```py
hover_text = models.HoverTool(tooltips=tooltips)
TOOLS_text = [hover_text, models.ResetTool(), models.BoxSelectTool()]

fig = plotting.figure(width=600, height=300, y_range=(0, 250),
                      x_range=data['month'].tolist(),
                      tools=TOOLS_text)
fig.text(x='wy_month', y='rain', text="month", text_color=blue, source=source, selection_text_color = "orange", nonselection_text_alpha=0.2)
fig.text(x='wy_month', y='snow', text="month", text_color=green, source=source, selection_color = "orange", nonselection_alpha=0.2)
plotting.show(fig)
```

Text can neither be selected nor does it change color nor are tooltips shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text glyphs only support point hit-testing, and even that only as of version 1.0 or later. So that means: hover tools and tap selection will work on text (1.0 or later), but box selections will not. You are welcome to open a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues) to discuss adding this feature. In the mean time, as a workaround, you could add some invisible circles using the same data source, just to drive the selection:

```
fig.circle(x='wy_month', y='snow', size=8, 
           alpha=0, nonselection_alpha=0, source=source)
fig.circle(x='wy_month', y='rain', size=8, 
           alpha=0, nonselection_alpha=0, source=source)
```

[image]